# Exporting svg from paper.js raster

Tags: javascript, svg, paperjs

I'm trying to export a svg from a raster script in paper.js.
The script however only seems to return the original (hidden) image instead of the vector content of the canvas.

I'm already very happy to get the script working, but need to get vector data to work with. I struggle to get any grip on what I'm doing wrong as it seems to work with scripts that don't feature rasters.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US-x-Hixie">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>TEST</title>        
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://paperjs.org/assets/js/paper.js"></script>

<script type="text/paperscript" canvas="canvas">  
var raster = new Raster('beaker');
raster.visible = false;
var gridSize = 5;
var spacing = 1.5;
raster.on('load', function() {
raster.size = new Size(200, 120);

for (var y = 0; y < raster.height; y++) {
    for(var x = 0; x < raster.width; x++) {
        var color = raster.getPixel(x, y);

        var path = new Path.Circle({
            center: new Point(x+((Math.random() * 1.5) - 0.75), y+((Math.random() * 1.5) - 0.75)) * gridSize,
            radius: gridSize / 1 / spacing,
            fillColor: 'black'
        });

        var grijs = color.gray * 100;
        var willekeur = Math.random() * grijs;
        if (willekeur < 20) {
            if (color.gray < 0.9) {
                if (color.gray < 0.1) {
                    path.scale(1.5);
                }
                else {
                    path.scale(1 - (color.gray/1.5));
                }
            }
            else {
                path.scale(0);
            }
        }
        else {
            path.scale(0);
        }


    }
}

project.activeLayer.position = view.center;

});

document.body.appendChild(project.exportSVG());

</script>



</head>

<body>


 <canvas id="canvas" width="1200" height="800"><img src="image/h.jpg" id="beaker">
</canvas>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to export to SVG before image is loaded and so, before anything is drawn.
You have to call `project.exportSVG()` after doing your image processing, inside the on load callback.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US-x-Hixie">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>TEST</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://paperjs.org/assets/js/paper.js"></script>

    <script type="text/paperscript" canvas="canvas">
        var raster = new Raster('beaker');
        raster.visible = false;
        var gridSize = 5;
        var spacing = 1.5;
        raster.on('load', function() {
            raster.size = new Size(200, 120);

            for (var y = 0; y < raster.height; y++) {
                for(var x = 0; x < raster.width; x++) {
                    var color = raster.getPixel(x, y);

                    var path = new Path.Circle({
                        center: new Point(x+((Math.random() * 1.5) - 0.75), y+((Math.random() * 1.5) - 0.75)) * gridSize,
                        radius: gridSize / 1 / spacing,
                        fillColor: 'black'
                    });

                    var grijs = color.gray * 100;
                    var willekeur = Math.random() * grijs;
                    if (willekeur < 20) {
                        if (color.gray < 0.9) {
                            if (color.gray < 0.1) {
                                path.scale(1.5);
                            }
                            else {
                                path.scale(1 - (color.gray/1.5));
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            path.scale(0);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        path.scale(0);
                    }


                }
            }

            project.activeLayer.position = view.center;

            // now you can export to SVG
            document.body.appendChild(project.exportSVG());
        });
    </script>



</head>

<body>


<canvas id="canvas" width="1200" height="800"><img src="image/h.jpg" id="beaker">
</canvas>



</body>

</html>
```